# Multiple DI-frameworks in a single ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is anyone aware of if its possible to have multiple DI-frameworks (for instance Unity and Ninject) within the same application. Or would the framework "collide" with each other?

Comment: it depents. it may works and may not :) if you need 2 frameworks - try to work with it, but be accurate

Comment: Ok, but I assume that if the developer that implements my "framework" has to be aware of the fact that Im using a DI-framework or else it might cause problems if he/she decides to just implement my framework and then simply also implements another DI-framework as well?

I might end up not using DI at all, but Im still very interested to hear what other has to say regarding this.. since it would be very nice to be able to use multiple DI-framework without making em interfere with each other.

Comment: You usually don't "require" a specific DI framework _within_ another framework.  If you do, then you're probably using some sort of "service locator" pattern where you're _pulling_ the dependency from the DI provider.  If you're going to build a framework and want to use DI, do it right and let the _user_ of the framework how to inject the dependencies.

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple DI containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible. But whether something makes sense is another matter.

You can create part of the object graph using DI framework 1, and then another part of the object graph with DI framework 2, and then you can wire/connect the two object graphs manually.

Please note that you probably shouldn't use a DI framework inside a class library (your framework). DI frameworks (or DI containers) should only be used inside applications (in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).

Quoting from the referenced article (Composition Root):

> Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't.

So, if you are just building some kind of framework (say for data access or email message processing), then you shouldn't use any DI container (DI and DI containers are different things). In your framework, you should enable DI, by declaring a class's dependencies in the constructor and making sure that such dependencies are abstract (e.g. declared as interfaces).

Consumers of your framework would then decide which DI container to use (or even if they want to use a DI container in the first place).

**In my opinion**, not using a DI container is better (even in applications). See [this article](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a reason why.